Sumproduct returns zero, but the numbers are fine
first time poster here.
I run into an issue where the sumproduct returns 0, thinking that it could be the problem with the numbers, I tried to multiply the value from the column, and adding them together, and returned the expected results.
Hoping to see if anyone here have any ideas on what's wrong.
[Edit: Excel is in Auto-calculation, the sumproduct was run on an index-match (figures on Col D and Col H are results of index match), and confirmed that the cells are numbers]
Using cell G100 as example, it was calculated by the following:

Col D * Col H = Col J
Sum all values from J2:J17
This create a "manual version" of sumproduct with expected value of 8681


So What's the formula you used that didn't give the expected results?

It is just your normal sumproduct formula, sorry for the error, as i thought the screen shot I had posted is shown there

There's no screenshot or formula, so we can't do much to confirm what's wrong or write what you need.
